# Sql Server select a single row as columns for sample data

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to be able to select a row of data but have the first column of output be column name and the second column of output be the value of that column for the selected row. How might I do this in SQL Server 2005 SSMS?

Comment: So you shoved [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) data into an relational database?

Comment: Nah this is just an exercise to make it easier to read the grid output for tables with a boatload of columns. Don't worry. I don't use this for any kind of dev.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) operator.